# Why does this prime test work?

Tags: python, algorithm, primes

I have found this Python function for testing whether or not a number is prime; however, I cannot figure out how the algorithm works.

```
def isprime(n):
   """Returns True if n is prime"""
   if n == 2: return True
   if n == 3: return True
   if n % 2 == 0: return False
   if n % 3 == 0: return False

   i = 5
   w = 2
   while i * i <= n:
      if n % i == 0:
         return False

      i += w
      w = 6 - w

   return True
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's start with the first four lines of the function's code:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n == 2: return True
    if n == 3: return True
    if n % 2 == 0: return False
    if n % 3 == 0: return False
```

The function tests to see if `n` is equal to 2 or 3 first. Since they are both prime numbers, the function will return `True` if `n` is equal to either.

Next, the function tests to see if `n` is divisible by 2 or 3 and returning `False` if either is true. This eliminates an extremely large amount of cases because half of all numbers above two are not primes - they are divisible by 2. The same reason applies to testing for divisibility by 3 - it also eliminates a large number of cases.

The trickier part of the function is in the next few lines:

```
i = 5
w = 2
while i * i <= n:
    if n % i == 0:
        return False

    i += w
    w = 6 - w

return True
```

First, `i` (or index) is set to 5. 2 and 3 have already been tested, and 4 was tested with `n % 2`. So, it makes sense to start at 5.

Next, `w` is set to 2. `w` seems to be an "incrementer". By now, the function has tested for all even numbers (`n % 2`), so it would be faster to increment by 2.

The function enters a `while` loop with the condition `i * i <= n`. This test is used because [every composite number has a proper factor less than or equal to its square root](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/number-theory/primes/primes.html). It wouldn't make sense to test numbers after the square root because it would be redundant.

In the `while` loop, if `n` is divisible by `i`, then it is not prime and the function returns `False`. If it is not, `i` is incremented by the "incrementer" `w`, which, again, is faster.

Perhaps the trickiest part of the function lies in the second-to-last line: `w = 6 - w`. This causes the "incrementer" `w` to toggle between the values 2 and 4 with each pass through loop. In cases where `w` is 4, we are bypassing a number divisible by 3. This is faster than remaining at 2 because the function already tested for divisibility by both 2 and 3.

Finally, the function returns `True`. If the function hasn't detected any cases where `n` is divisible by something, then it must be a prime number.

Answer (score 3):

Except 2 and 3 all prime number can represent using (6*n)+1 or (6*n)-1, where n is 0 to infinite.
This program is working according to this idea.
Using this lines check number can divisible by 2 or 3

```
 if n % 2 == 0: return False
 if n % 3 == 0: return False
```

Then we need to check number can divisible by other prime numbers grater than 3.

```
i = 5
w = 2
while i * i <= n:
   if n % i == 0:
       return False

   i += w
   w = 6 - w
```

The next prime number is 5. Therefore initial value of i set as 5.
To get all number in set (6*n)+1 or (6*n)-1 alternatively change the value of w (2,4). 
And this snippet used to check up to square root of  the number.

```
 while i * i <= n:
```

This code is not efficient because some non prime numbers in set (6*n)+1 or (6*n)-1.